# order by nearest value in mysql

Tags: mysql

Need optimized query on the below search functionality

Product table

```
Product      att1   att2      att3    att4    att5

p1            1       2         2       3       2
p2            4       1         1       5       5
p3            5       3         5       3       2
p4            4       4         2       1       1
```

if user search att1 = 3 , att2 = 2 and att3 = 5

then, we need to display all the records in order by the maximum possible
ratings of the all required attributes

Note : -  in first row there is only one possible matches found.
   -  in second row nothing found,
   - in third row one matches found

So based on the number of matching, we need to order the records,
If exact match not found, then relaxation on the search
elements

Comment: Perhaps search not by `=` but by `attx >= queryValue - lowRange AND attx <= queryValue + highRange` and also add a calculated field to the select which equals `attx - queryValue AS distancex`, this field will contain the distance of the match from the specified value and you can use it for sorting.

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from product
order by (att1 = 3) + (att2 = 2) + (att3 = 5) desc
```

This works because in mysql `true` is `1` and `false` is `0`, so summing the conditions gives you the number of search criteria matches. Ordering `desc` returns them "closest match first"